# NUnit Tests not running and have blue exclamation Icon next to them

Tags: nunit, tdd

Are you trying to tests out some methods, but when it comes down to it your tests arent even running?

Typically they might have a blue exclamation point next to them and when you run all tests the output is something like:

```
0 tests run 0 tests passed 0 tests failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This typically happens when you dont install the NUnit3TestAdapater.

Run this in the package manager console (tools > Nugest Package Manager > Package Manager Console)

```
Install-Package Nunit3TestAdapter
```

and then clean build your solution

and then run all tests and voila!

They should be running again (whether they pass or fail is up to you!)

Answer (score 2):

I had the NUnit3TestAdapter but still had this problem.

Solution for me (as found over internet by a colleague) was deleting TestStore folder. Restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding the project made the tests working.

Before that, I changed csproj files for the tests to run as 32 bit. This was done by changing the PropertyGroup as following

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also, I set the test adapter to run as x86.

**Deleting the "TestStore" folder was final step and before that (only with two changes above) tests still didn't run.** So they might be needed as well but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes, unfortunately this is one of those annoying issues where it isnt any one thing, but potentially many. thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting a bit longer after a rebuild.

MSVS appeared to be idle for a few minutes with the test showing blue icon with exclamation point.  But then suddenly the progress slider at the top of the test explorer became active so I just waited and a minute or so later the Run/Debug Test menu item became available.

So if you can get that progress slider to animate (perhaps by rebuilding one or more projects and then being idle) it may fix itself.